# need to prase dynamic json data in angular 8

Tags: json, parsing, dynamic, angular8

my json data is

```
{
    "status": "Sucess",
    "data": {
        "id": 3,
        "permissions": {
            "logentry": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Can change log entry",
                    "status": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Can delete log entry",
                    "status": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Can view log entry",
                    "status": 0
                }
            ],
            "company": [
                {
                    "id": 29,
                    "name": "Can add company",
                    "status": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 30,
                    "name": "Can change company",
                    "status": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 31,
                    "name": "Can delete company",
                    "status": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 32,
                    "name": "Can view company",
                    "status": 0
                }
            ],
            "contenttype": [
                {
                    "id": 17,
                    "name": "Can add content type",
                    "status": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 18,
                    "name": "Can change content type",
                    "status": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "name": "Can delete content type",
                    "status": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 20,
                    "name": "Can view content type",
                    "status": 0
                }
            ],
            "moduletype": [
                {
                    "id": 25,
                    "name": "Can add module type",
                    "status": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 26,
                    "name": "Can change module type",
                    "status": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 27,
                    "name": "Can delete module type",
                    "status": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 28,
                    "name": "Can view module type",
                    "status": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        "name": "manager"
    },
    "message": "Successful Response data"
}
```

I need to parse the data and get permissions contents in my component using angular 8
here permission key like **lognetry, comapany, contenttype, moduletype** all are dynamically generated.

I am new in angular i tried this way to get details
Recived json data through service and assigned in **data**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
    <div *ngFor="let temp of item.permissions |keyvalue">
        <div *ngFor="let temp1 of temp|keyvalue ">
            Key: <b>{{temp1.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{temp1.value}}</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need solution to print all data like this way in my component
can any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it by using three loops.

```
<div *ngFor="let permission_item of pemissions">
      <div *ngFor="let item of permission_item.permissions |keyvalue">
    
        Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b>
        <div *ngFor="let permissionObj of item.value">
          {{permissionObj.id}} {{permissionObj.name}} {{permissionObj.status}}
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
      </div>
```

please comment you need any clarifications